# Save PostGIS login informations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

Does anyone know a way to save my username for PostGIS in QGIS, so I'll always be logged in without the need to enter my username and password everytime?

Anytime I start new project in QGIS, I need to log in and enter my username and my password and I wonder if there is any way that it will always be logged in and I'll not have to insert my username and password.

Comment: Is it **PostGIS** or **QGIS** or Postgis under QGIS ? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I saw the tags but for clarity and question referencing, it's not ideal.

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: I have edit it, I meant Postgresql in qgis. I'm bew to this so i'm sorry if it sounds confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save the connection settings to your PostGresql database to avoid typing your password every time in Qgis.

You can use a pgpass configuration file : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

it's a text file situated in your user space and you just need to type your login:password in this file.
This file should exist in your installation (otherwise create it), you just need to edit it and add your login:password

NB : it's not safe to use it this way but it's ok if it's a local database.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm new to this. so I would love to know, what is the user space, how can I find it ? this text fille should cintain only the code as appaeard in that link with the correct data filled in this- hostname:port:database:username:password -and can I  create it on notepad and then just put this text document in my user space?

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way, using QGIS 3.20.3.

On the left in the Browser Tab, click "Edit Connection" on the PostGIS Connection you want to save, and in the Popup under Authentication -> Configurations, create a new Authentication Configuration.

On a Mac, this prompted me to first set a Master Password, and then offered to save this Master Password in my KeyChain, so I don't even have to enter it when I start QGIS.

I did however have to delete and recreate the layer that was using this connection, as it kept asking me for the DB connection credentials every time I started QGIS. Once I recreated the layer it stopped asking me for that every time.